# EF Code First, Composite Foreign Key with static Part

Tags: .net, entity-framework-4, mapping, composite-primary-key

I have a problem with EF 4.2 Code First on an existing SQL DB.

I have multiple Entities like Corporate, User, etc.

Common information is stored in a seprate table called Entity with primary Key [EntityId, EntityTypeId].

- EntityId corresponds to CorporateId, UserId, etc.
- EntityTypeId is a static Id used like discrimiator between the entities

I have the following class design.

```
public class User
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int EntityTypeId { get { return 1; } set { }}
    public Entity Entity {get;set;}
}

public class Entity
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int EntityTypeId {get;set;}
}
```

As you can see the EntityTypeId is static Property and there is no corresponding column in the User Table.

Maps:

```
public UserMap()
{
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("User");
        this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("UserId");

        // Relationships
        this.HasRequired(t => t.Entity)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(p => new { p.Id, p.EntityTypeId });  //<-- Problem
    }


public EntityMap()
{
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => new { t.Id, t.EntityTypeId });

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("Entity");
        this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("EntityId");
        this.Property(t => t.EntityTypeId).HasColumnName("EntityTypeId");
}
```

When I run this code I am getting the error:
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'EntityTypeId'.

I assume it's because the column EntityTypeId doesn't exist on the User table.
Is there a way around this Problem, as I can't create this Column on the Table?!

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

This is even not valid FK in the database and EF use exactly same rules as database to define relationships as a database so you will not be able to map this relation.

This looks more like a combination of TPH and TPT inheritance but EF doesn't like this combination and is not able to map it (or at least I was never able to make it fully work). For example to start with TPH, EF doesn't allow discriminator in primary key.